# TestNG custom reporter - adding stacktrace to report

Tags: java, selenium, testng, reporting

I am using a custom reporter for my TestNG suite. I borrowed the basic code from an online tutorial, and have made some adjustments. However, I want to include a stack trace for any failed tests, in the same way the in-built report does (emailable-report.html). Simply appending what's seen in this report to the bottom of mine would be fine.

Can anyone give me any pointers on how this could be achieved? I have no idea how to access the stack traces.

This is the generateReport method (there's lots more I could show but might not be relevant):

```
@Override
    public void generateReport(List<XmlSuite> xmlSuites, List<ISuite> suites, String outputDirectory) {

        try {
            // Get content data in TestNG report template file.
            String customReportTemplateStr = this.readEmailableReportTemplate();

            // Create custom report title.
            String customReportTitle = this.getCustomReportTitle(Base.Client + " Regression Suite Report");

            // Create test suite summary data.
            String customSuiteSummary = this.getTestSuiteSummary(suites);

            // Create test methods summary data.
            String customTestMethodSummary = this.getTestMethodSummary(suites);

            // Replace report title place holder with custom title.
            customReportTemplateStr = customReportTemplateStr.replaceAll("\\$TestNG_Custom_Report_Title\\$",
                    customReportTitle);

            // Replace test suite place holder with custom test suite summary.
            customReportTemplateStr = customReportTemplateStr.replaceAll("\\$Test_Case_Summary\\$", customSuiteSummary);

            // Replace test methods place holder with custom test method summary.
            customReportTemplateStr = customReportTemplateStr.replaceAll("\\$Test_Case_Detail\\$",
                    customTestMethodSummary);

            // Write replaced test report content to custom-emailable-report.html.
            File targetFile = new File(outputDirectory + "/custom-emailable-report.html");
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(targetFile);
            fw.write(customReportTemplateStr);
            fw.flush();
            fw.close();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

...and this is the html template:

```
<body>
    <table>
      <tr><center><font size="5" face="verdana">
        <b>$TestNG_Custom_Report_Title$</b>
      </font></center></tr>
      <p></p>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th># Total Method</th>
          <th># Passed</th>
          <th># Skipped</th>
          <th># Failed</th>
          <th>Start Time</th>
          <th>End Time</th>
          <th>Execute Time (hh:mm:ss)</th>
        </tr>
       </thead> 
       $Test_Case_Summary$
    </table>
    <table id="summary">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Class</th>
          <th>Method</th>
          <th>Start Time</th>
          <th>Execution Time (hh:mm:ss)</th>
          <th>Browser</th>
          <th>Screenshot</th>
        </tr>
      </thead> 
      $Test_Case_Detail$
    </table>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.testng.internal.Utils;

private void generateResult(ITestResult ans){
    ITestResult ans;
    List<String> msgs = Reporter.getOutput(ans);
    Throwable exception = ans.getThrowable();

    boolean hasThrowable = exception != null;
    if (hasThrowable) {
       String stackTraceMsg = Utils.stackTrace(exception, true)[0];
    }
}
```